# Missing context for method declaration - In-app receipt verificationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

App was running fine but on Xcode 6 its having error "Missing context for method declaration" on the method below:

```
- (NSString *)encodeBase64:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length{
    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        for (NSInteger j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;
            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }
        NSInteger index = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[index + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[index + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[index + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[index + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }
    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data    encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
}

// Exact code above @end is : 

/*
- (NSString *)encodeBase64:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length
{ 
#warning Replace this method.
return nil;
}


- (NSString *)decodeBase64:(NSString *)input length:(NSInteger *)length
{
#warning Replace this method.
return nil;
}

#warning Implement this function.
char* base64_encode(const void* buf, size_t size)
{ return NULL; }

#warning Implement this function.
void * base64_decode(const char* s, size_t * data_len)
{ return NULL; }

*/
@end
```

Comment: Where did you put this code?

Comment: in VerficationController.m ( class provided by Apple)

Comment: Where exactly ? Could you show the file? Before the `@end`? Could you show what's before it and what's after it?

Comment: /*
- (NSString *)encodeBase64:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length
{
#warning Replace this method.
    return nil;
}


- (NSString *)decodeBase64:(NSString *)input length:(NSInteger *)length
{
#warning Replace this method.
    return nil;
}

#warning Implement this function.
char* base64_encode(const void* buf, size_t size)
{ return NULL; }

#warning Implement this function.
void * base64_decode(const char* s, size_t * data_len)
{ return NULL; }

*/
@end

Comment: Could you update your question (for the formatting) instead of doing it in the comments?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61353/discussion-between-zubair-and-larme).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well. It seems to be that with Xcode6+, they don't want you putting C/C++ code inside an Objective-C context.

I moved the C/C++ code that was in the VerificationController to before the @implementation / @end block and it compiled fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend:

a) Double-checking that your method exists in-between @implementation and @end within the file

b) Removing

```
- (NSString *)encodeBase64:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length
{ 
  #warning Replace this method.
  return nil;
}
```

if it still exists in the elsewhere in the file (seems to be what your comments in the original post are suggesting) ?

Answer (score 1):

I had also faced the same issue with Xcode 6.0.1.

Rearranging the methods like this ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/btNzL.png ) silenced the errors ("Missing context for method declaration" and "'@end' must appear in an Objective-C context" ) for me. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Could you please post the final VerificationController.m code? I've tried to rearrange it as you did but the errors persist... Cheers

Comment: Hello jeddi, I have uploaded the .m file here: https://www.mediafire.com/?449p3xul53rfcf3

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. Could you please also post the h file? I think it differs from mine as I get quite a few errors... Cheers

Comment: I am also adding "UIDevice+IdentifierAddition" class files as referenced in the .h file: https://www.mediafire.com/?hh18g5itxcjg113

Comment: That's awesome, thank you so much! However I get this error in my code below when I call verifyPurchase. Am I doing it in the wrong way?  
//Error: verif contr/MyGame/UpgradeViewController.m:353:15: No visible @interface for 'VerificationController' declares the selector 'verifyPurchase:completionHandler:'

Comment: This is my code in UpgradeViewController.m

- (void)validateReceiptForTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    VerificationController * verifier = [VerificationController sharedInstance];
    [verifier verifyPurchase:transaction completionHandler:^(BOOL success) 
 {if (success) {
            NSLog(@"Successfully verified receipt!");
            
            [self UnlockContent];} 
 else {NSLog(@"Failed to validate receipt.");
      [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];}}];}

Comment: I've changed  from //[verifier verifyPurchase:transaction completionHandler:^(BOOL success) // to //[verifier verifyPurchase:^(BOOL success)// and it works! Thanks! :-)